# Combined numpy/sympy problem: one class with "if"s or abstract classes?

Tags: python, numpy, oop, abstract-class, sympy

I am developing a code that mixes algebraic (using numpy) and symbolic (using sympy) linear algebra. Some cases may be treated with a fully symbolic approach, some other require a fully algebraic treatment, and the mixed symbolic/algebraic case may also occur. The main reason is that for some problems, using symbolic algebra will just take infinite time to run and so switching to numerical calculations will be required... On the other hand, symbolic math will be faster for other problems.

I have in mind to deal with the problem using some "Matrix" and "Vector" objects, for which I have redefined common mathematical operations that have a precise meaning - not completely usual though - for my problem (sum `__sum__`, product `__mul__` and `__rmul__`, inverse `.inv()`, derivative `.diff(t)`, etc.). Then either numpy or sympy functions are called behind, depending on the case. The main idea is to **keep the symbolic/algebraic backend as transparent as possible**, because subsequent algorithms should work using this "user-defined" algebra without needing to know if there is behind symbolic or algebraic math.

(1) A first idea I have is to declare one class with "if"'s inside each method, like e.g.

```py
class Matrix():

    def __init__(self,dtype='sympy'):
        self._dtype = dtype

    def method(self):
        if self._dtype == 'sympy':
            print('Does some stuff using symbolic math')
        if self._dtype == 'numpy':
            print('Does some stuff using algebraic math')
```

(2) I also thought of an abstract class "Matrix" associated with concrete classes "npMatrix" and "syMatrix", like e.g.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Matrix(ABC):

    def __new__(cls,dtype='sympy'):
        subclass_map = {
            subclass.DTYPE: subclass for subclass in cls.__subclasses__()
            }
        subclass = subclass_map[dtype]
        instance = super(Matrix, subclass).__new__(subclass)
        return instance

    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass

class syMatrix(Matrix):

    DTYPE = 'sympy'

    def __new__(self):
        return super(Matrix, syMatrix).__new__(syMatrix)

    def method(self):
        print('Does some stuff using symbolic math')


class npMatrix(Matrix):

    DTYPE = 'numpy'

    def __new__(self):
        return super(Matrix, npMatrix).__new__(npMatrix)

    def method(self):
        print('Does some stuff using algebraic math')
```

In both cases, the syntax is the same for the user, the switch between sympy or numpy backend being made by *dtype*:

```py
S = Matrix(dtype='sympy')
S.method() # prints 'Does some stuff using symbolic math'

N = Matrix(dtype='numpy')
N.method() # prints 'Does some stuff using algebraic math'
```

Now, it's a bit difficult for me to decide between one or the other implementation...

- Option (1) seems to be more compact, maybe easier to maintain as the code grows ?
- Option (2) avoids having to test the dtype within each function: would it be considered as a good practice? Negligible in terms of performances? Also my implementation works but seems a bit complicated compared to option (1)
- Maybe there is a better option, other than (1) and (2) ?
- On the long run, performance may become an issue. Are there any approaches that should be favoured for some obvious reason?

I'm not very familiar with software architecture so any suggestion is welcome :-)
Thanks

Comment: Either approach can be fine depending on context. Option 1 is not great if *every* method has to branch on the same condition. I'd probably go with Option 2 except I wouldn't bother with the ABC: just make two classes with the same interface (duck-typing). The important part is choosing a good common interface for those two classes.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested a bit further Option (2) ; seems to work fine. Finally I kept however ABC/@abstractmethods so as to keep kind of a "well-defined structure". This is maybe overkill, but otherwise I'm afraid I'll forget at some point to implement each function both in the concrete npMatrix and syMatrix classes...